# Msql: Counting growth over time

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I posted about this a few weeks ago, but I don't think I asked the question clearly because the answers I got were not what I was looking for.  I think it's best to start again.

I'm trying to query a database to retrieve the number of unique entries over time.  The data looks something like this:

`Day` | `UserID`
1   | A
1   | B
2   | B
3   | A
4   | B
4   | C
5   | D

I'd like the query result to look this this

Time Span      | COUNT(DISTINCT `UserID`)
Day 1 to Day 1 |  2
Day 1 to Day 2 |  2
Day 1 to Day 3 |  2
Day 1 to Day 4 |  3
Day 1 to Day 5 |  4

If I do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `UserID`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `Day`
```

, the distinct counts will not consider user IDs of previous days.

Any Ideas?  The data set I'm using is quite large, so multiple-queries and post processing takes a long time (that's how I'm currently doing it).

Thanks

Comment: You are interested in the number of "unique visitors" in a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery

#### Sample table

```
create table visits (day int, userid char(1));
insert visits values
(1,'a'),
(1,'b'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'a'),
(4,'b'),
(4,'c'),
(5,'d');
```

#### The query

```
select d.day, (select count(distinct userid) from visits where day<=d.day)
from (select distinct day from visits) d
```

Comment: Thanks!  Nice solution.  I made 1 modification.  I'm not sure if it's faster.  In the query after the main FROM, I used GROUP BY day instead of DISTINCT day

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this:

```
SELECT Count(UserID), Day 
FROM     
    (SELECT Count(UserID) as Logons, UserID, Day 
    FROM yourDailyLog
    GROUP BY Day, UserID)
GROUP BY Day
```

The inner select should eliminate the duplicate visits by a same user on a given day.

Stay away from DISTINCT. It is usually a questionable approach to almost any SQL problem.

Wait: I see now that you want the time period to increase over time. That makes things a little trickier. Why don't you aggregate the rest of this information in code rather than doing it all through sql?