# Mysql refrencing derived tables from nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, derived-table, subquery

I posted something similar to this yesterday, but now I'd like something a little different from my query-

I'm trying to query a database to retrieve the number of one-time users who have visited a website over time. The data looks something like this:

```
Day | UserID  
  1 | A  
  1 | B  
  2 | B  
  3 | A  
  4 | B  
  4 | C  
  5 | D
```

I'd like the query result to look this this

```
Time Span      | COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)  
Day 1 to Day 1 | 2  
Day 1 to Day 2 | 1  
Day 1 to Day 3 | 0  
Day 1 to Day 4 | 1  
Day 1 to Day 5 | 2
```

*The result is 2,1,0,1,2 because, at the end of those days, there are X number of users who have visited a single time. e.g. for day 5, at the end of day 5, users c and d have visited only once each.*

I think I'm looking for a query similar to this:

```
select d.day, (select count(distinct userid) from visits where day<=d.day)
from (select distinct day from visits) d
```

The difference between the query above and what I'm looking for is that I'd like this new query to consider only one-time users for each time span, and not repeat users.

Thanks

Comment: For one time users, shouldn't the result be 2,0,0,1,1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This subquery should work for the clarified requirements.

```
select d.day, count(distinct case when b.userid is null then a.userid end)
from (select day from visits group by day) d
inner join
(
select a.day, a.userid, count(*) c
from visits a
join visits b on a.userid=b.userid and b.day <= a.day
group by a.day, a.userid
having count(*) = 1
) a on a.day <= d.day
left join
(
select a.day, a.userid, count(*) c
from visits a
join visits b on a.userid=b.userid and b.day <= a.day
group by a.day, a.userid
having count(*) > 1
) b on a.userid = b.userid and b.day <= d.day
group by d.day
```

#### Original

You must have taken the idea from SQL Server - it is the only RDBMS (IIRC) that will allow you to reference a twice removed (nesting) query. Please indicate what you want and we can rewrite the query.

For the exact query shown, you don't need 2 levels of subquery

```
SELECT  
    C.col_c1 AS Data,
    (
        SELECT count(col_b1)
        FROM tbl
        WHERE col_b2 <= C.col_c1
    ) A
FROM (
    SELECT col_c1 # subquery to get distinct c1
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY col_c1) C;
```

Comment: Basically I'm going one step beyond my post from yesterday which was successfully answered.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317917/msql-counting-growth-over-time    This time I'd like the query to show growth of unique users who have visited only once.  My last post was broader considering one-time AND repeat user growth over time.  Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Tucker fyi - if it has been successfully answered, you should tick next to the answer that solved the question

Comment: @Richard aka cyberwiki  Thanks for the suggestion, I made the edit to the post.  I think its a lot more clear now.

Comment: I tested your new query, but it didn't give the right results.  The first-time user counts yielded (in chronological order)  2,0,0,1,1 for each time span.  Still trying to figure out why though.   thanks

Comment: From Day 1 and Day 2, there are three visits.  1st from user a, 2nd from user b, and 3rd from user b.  user b in that span is a repeat user.  user a is still a one time user.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi  Keep in mind that the one-time user count looks back to all previous days.  You are correct in that user a didn't visit on day 2.  But in the time-span from day1 to day2, user a visited once and user b twice.  Therefore in that time span there is only 1 one-time user.  The same logic applies to subsequent days.  Does that make sense?  Thanks again for your assistance.  I've been struggling with this on and off for a few days now.

Comment: Your clarification is confirmed.

Comment: @Tucker - Answer updated to match clarified question. I deleted all comments to clean up the question/answer :)